# JS Multiply last children in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to multiply the last children of an array by a variable number for use in a chart but I can't get the multiplier to work.

Here's my code:

```
var data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3,12,43,60,78,98,130];
data.slice(-6, 13)*1.2;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umc4the1/)

Comment: please add what you want to multiply. an d the result of it.

Comment: The result of `data.slice` is still an array. Now, does it makes sense to try and multiple an array with a factor …? No, of course not.

Comment: Do you want to multiply each item with the number or multiply all the items with each other and then multiply the result by the number? Do you expect an array or a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get the following values multiplied by 1.2,

```
[12, 43, 60, 78, 98, 130]
```

You can use the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) method :

```
var data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3,12,43,60,78,98,130];
data.slice(-6, 13).map(function(el) { return el * 1.2;})

// => [14.399999999999999, 51.6, 72, 93.6, 117.6, 156]
```

and if you want to keep them in the array, you can do the following :

```
var data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3,12,43,60,78,98,130];
data.map(function(el, i) { return i >= 6 ? el * 1.2 : el});
```

Hope it helps,

Best regards

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

`data.slice(-6, 13)` - gives you an array, you can't multiply an array. You need to loop through values and multiply them.

```js
var data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3,12,43,60,78,98,130];
var dataToMultiply = data.slice(-6, 13);
var multipliedData = [];

dataToMultiply.forEach(function(element) {
    multipliedData.push(element * 1.2);
});

console.log(multipliedData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it like:

```
var test = (data.slice(-6, 13).map(x =>x*1.2));
```